# function event depending on appended div with class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following problem. I'm appending a div with class "scrolling" for a javascript customized scrollbar, and I'm appending the div dynamically. After that, I set up the scrollbar.

The problem is that it does not work with a div which was appended. When I'm trying it with a div which is hardcoded to the document everything works fine.

```
function appenddiv() {
    $('#container').append('<div id="test" class="scrolling"> Lorem Ipsum ...... </div>');

    $('.scrolling').scrollbar();
}
```

I also tried

```
function appenddiv() {
    $('#container').append('<div id="test"> Lorem Impsum .....</div>');
    $('#test').addClass('scrolling');

    $('.scrolling').scrollbar();
}
```

I tried it with just a button

```
<a href="#" onClick="appenddiv">Click here</a>
```

the only thing which works is:

```
<body>
   <div id="test" class="scrolling"> Lorem Ipsum ..... </div>

   <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $('.scrolling').scrollbar(); //this is not fired in the examples above!
        });
```

As I said, it only works when the div test with class scrollbar is already in the body. The function scrollbar is a jquery-customized scrollbar script, located [here](https://github.com/thomd/jquery-scroll/)

Comment: Well, on the first, you're accessing a class `scrolling`, but using the class `scrollbar.` On the second, you're accessing a class `test`, but using an id `test.` Those both may be typos in the question, but without an example, that's the place to start.

Comment: Did you try to use delay?

Comment: sorry guys it was a typing fault! i mean im using both scrolling! sry

Comment: everyone is focusing on the typing errors, and stuff has been upvoted that wasnt the solution. its a callback problem, jQuery isnt recognizing the items dynamically added to the DOM.

Comment: @LifeInTheGrey, the typing problem was not pointed out corrected until later. I deleted my answer, but it's not that people were focusing on the wrong problem, it's that the problem actually changed.

Comment: @LifeInTheGrey, but it's not that jquery isn't recognizing items dynamically added to the dom either. That explanation doesn't make sense. $.fn.append is synchronous, and as soon as it is done, any future jquery selectors will apply to what was just added.

Comment: @TedMosby, can you please edit your question to include an example of the static codeblock that *does* work?

Comment: of course i can do that!

Comment: @TedMosby, is the place that you call your `appenddiv()` method wrapped in a `$(document).ready(function() {})` callback? If not, that's the problem. If so, please post the code the calls appenddiv(), it seems like the problem is outside the scope of the appendiv method itself.

Comment: i tried it with just a button `<a href="#" onClick="appenddiv">Click here</a>`

Comment: @TedMosby, well that's the problem. I just edited your question to include what you tried to call it, and then updated and undeleted my answer explaining why that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the `onClick` handler in your button is not actually calling the method, it is just referencing it. You have to use parenthesis to call it. And return false to prevent the default link action. So try this:

```
<a href="#" onClick="appenddiv(); return false;">Click here</a>
```

Also, you have to make sure that your function is defined at the time you call this. Since you're using jQuery, the best way to do this is to not use `onclick` at all, but instead put everything in a document ready callback, and use an on-click handler. So your html link would just be like this:

```
<a href="#" id="scrollbar-link">Click here</a>
```

And your javascript like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function appenddiv() {
        var $scrolling = $('<div id="test" class="scrolling"> Lorem Ipsum ...... </div>');
        $scrolling.appendTo($('#container')).scrollbar();
    }

    $('#scrollbar-link').on('click', function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault(); // This stops the browser from following the link
        appenddiv();
    });
});
```

Comment: what can i say? it worked, thank you very much ben lee, this helped me alot!

Answer (score 0):

These both have CSS selector errors.

In the first case, you're trying to match a jQuery selector for class `.scrolling`, but the class is `.scrollbar` when you append it to the document - so the selector won't match.

In the second case, the jQuery selector on the second line is for a class `.test`, but you appended an element with an *id* `#test`. Again, this won't match any elements in your document.

Other than these errors, it appears at first glance that your code should work fine. Fix those errors and give it another shot.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example `$('.scrolling').scrollbar();`

should be `$('.scrollbar').scrollbar();`

And in your second example, `$('.test').addClass('scrolling');`

should be `$('#test').addClass('scrolling');`

`#` refers to an id, while `.` refers to a class.

Answer (score -1):

In first fragment you try to add div with class = "scrollbar", but use "scrolling" class selector ($('.scrolling').scrollbar();). Try use the same name.

In second fragment you add div with id = "test", but after that you try to add class to element with class = "test". Try use

```
$('#test').addClass('scrolling');
```

or

```
$('#test').scrollbar();
```